# How many distinct combinations of 10 pairs from 20 elements is possible without repetition?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorial-designs

I would like to know how can I calculate how many possible groups of 10 exclusive pairs can I draw out of a permutation list of 20 elements. I'm able to calculate the 190 pairs from 20 elements, and now I want to draw 10 pairs at a time and make it so the next draw there's no repetition from the previous. My C# algorithm tells me I can draw 9 times before running out of exclusive pairs. Why is it 9?

The gist of the algorithm is:

1. Get a permutation list of the 20 elements in exclusive pairs (no A = B)
2. Draws a pair of the permutation list, check if either A or B is not present in resulting list, remove from the permutation list, and repeat 9 extra times, resulting in 10 exclusive pairs.

I can see 9 groups of 10 exclusive pairs and then the algorithm can't find any other exclusive pair to draw.

Comment: You can get 19 draws, using the [round robin tournament schedule described at Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you, this seem to be less complicated then what I was initially doing

Answer (score 0):

Check out this related question. [Number of ways of dividing 20 persons into 10 couples](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2481417/number-of-ways-of-dividing-20-persons-into-10-couples)

If it is still not working, please post your code so that we can see if there is an issue with the algorithm. Without it, it's difficult to tell.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Mike sent a link to an algorithm at the original question which seemed faster and better. Decided to go that way. Thank you!